# How to have a function in an abstract class return instances of a child classes in typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, abstract-class, parent-child, extends

Is it possible to have something like this pseudocode:

```
abstract class AbstractParent {
    protected value: number;
    constructor(value: number) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    ...
    public times(multiplicator: number) {
        return new ???(value * multiplicator);
    }
}
```

Which returns a new `Foo` for `class Foo extends AbstractParent` and a new `Bar` for `class Bar extends AbstractParent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maintainable way is to keep the `times` calculation in the base class, and implement separate `create` factory methods inside `Foo` and `Bar`. This way, the base class is not  aware of its extending child classes.

You declare `create` as `abstract` in `AbstractParent` to make sure it will be implemented in all sub classes. The [polymorphic this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) return type ensures for the caller of `times`, that the returned instance has the same sub class type ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIAVgoBTAO0QG8AoBWhABygHsJj5iATBAN2GQFdiALgSl+AWxDEoAbio06sJqUhR+8JlAAUvAcNESpUAJQJqdCwggALAJZgAdLsEIAvDz6C5FgL7yL9PwgyLawVrbixGBa4vzIELb0IbDAEJoiYpLSpuaWtCQQ-FCkVnaOsCSpxFo29k6exAgAVAix8YnJqZrG3nR+CrQA9IMIAGZ4mgCercQ2TFwVxFUYtioQwKSwUQhMowhgwJEMTMiT4pr0dmEQk-SNWgBiTEwIIwBCRMYDDMys7FygVR4JCVVg6BoZQzZES1MBUfooNAYJ4vYgAD1YpA4GGwQPghBI5DM-kUoOqzn0mSMOW+FmGCHwJzOFyupXsVlujXZKIQ1mkxAANPsXrYIAByDAAeQA0lYXgUiiVgAgUQ5aXR6QBhJjiei2ZDSBDs0gsBDAADuREau1KjUR6CQylYGKFYBe5rtaAgDgQ6vys0VomI5pVz3BelMaDZcN88Pk9owHygCHRmOxWBwMHxVqJuSGIwORyjKO+iyq4cEkKyJmJeX9hWKQZDSYrxEjGFh3z8COUkDGzzcTdDTC0ABYAEzGBwJSLRSevEYlpRrBAgIiD0jBhAtidTmdRLQAZlM9KTQA)).

```
abstract class AbstractParent {
    protected value: number;

    constructor(value: number) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    times(multiplicator: number) {
        return this.create(this.value * multiplicator);
    }

    // factory method creates instances of same polymorphic type (Foo / Bar)
    protected abstract create(value: number): this
}

class Foo extends AbstractParent {

    create(value: number) {
        // Polymorphic this type is Foo here, so it's OK to return a Foo.
        // Compiler is not aware of the class context, so we cast. 
        return new Foo(value) as this
    }
}

class Bar extends AbstractParent {
    // same as Foo
    create(value: number) {
        return new Bar(value) as this
    }
}

const foo = new Foo(42).times(2) // Foo
const bar = new Bar(42).times(3) // Bar
```

Comment: I agree that the [factory method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a good choice here. However, I do not understand your implementation choices...
The method `times` should call the factory method. The factory method should be protected. And an implementation of the factory method should only instantiate the corresponding class (without call to the method times).

Comment: You are right, mixed that one up from a previous alternative in mind. `times` is public in OP's question, so it makes more sense to have a public base `times` method, that invokes a polymorphic protected factory method internally. Updated answer, thanks!

Comment: thanks. I tried this approach, now I get `TypeError: this.create is not a function` when I try to do  `const foo = new Foo(42).times(2)`

Comment: @Hade0011 `TypeError` is a JavaScript run time error not related to TS. Playground in the answer works, so can you provide a sample? Sounds more like you mixed up the `this` context somewhere ...

Comment: @ford04 You are exactly right. I fixed my `this` and now it is working like a charm. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the child type into the parent constructor and save a reference. This prevents the parent having to know about all the possible child types (though I agree with the other answer that there may be a better way to achieve your overall goal). Something like this ([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgSwDYBMYHsB2BnYAnAVwGNh08AeeZFAPigF4pMIB3KACgDcBDJAiAFxMCAWwBGEPABooRRKgw58xUniFUFWXIRJlK82gEoGdDSgDcAKEvcx27iVlJu2bFACCd-A+AAFbngQmMD61FAQAB7AQShunvYk-oHBoag0dADellA5UGB46NEkEChQPHyCwuKSVrl5BUXRpXLUitoqZOoGbcq6FGY0Vtm5RFq9qly8-EKYohLSst1jOqpdrcsd-QY0xll1dcCI2AB05fwMZVMQtfs5hwgnLZpKK2QXT2gbfTc5AL7WdTABDESAQRCgwAQIgg2HYIgISEhYFBRG4qyq80Ma1QUD2tyggWABDwmCYrAhR2OHx6rzw7HuJzO0AAVFB4YiEMiwWiyDIGVSli9NoYflB-v9LERnK4oAAxdDocJRGJxLx4HxJIIheXoTLDHKjIV9SYVGZzSS7fX7bAESB0pkyHUiq3i6xSlxuABCASV0UwsQ8ao1AS15G9eD1dUN7WNTLN1TwlvxUBtdpN-Bk4eddXFQA)):

```
type ChildConstructor<Child> = new (value: number, childConstructor: ChildConstructor<Child>) => Child;

abstract class AbstractParent<Child extends AbstractParent<Child>> {
    protected value: number;
    protected childConstructor: ChildConstructor<Child>;

    constructor(value: number, childConstructor: ChildConstructor<Child>) {
        this.value = value;
        this.childConstructor = childConstructor;
    }

    public times(multiplicator: number): Child {
        return new this.childConstructor(this.value * multiplicator, this.childConstructor);
    }
}

class Foo extends AbstractParent<Foo> {
    constructor(value: number) {
        super(value, Foo);
    }
}

class Bar extends AbstractParent<Bar> {
    constructor(value: number) {
        super(value, Bar);
    }
}
```

Note that to get 100% type safety, each child class would need to have at least one additional private property or method to keep TypeScript's "duck typing" from considering the classes to be interchangeable (since they share the same properties and methods).